# Can&#39;t scroll navigation menu

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I using Testcafe.
I have a problem about clicking elements bottom of the navigation bar.

---

Test Url: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/

Test Code:

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe'

fixture('scroll')

test('Can scroll sidebar', async t => {
    await t
        .navigateTo('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/')
        .resizeWindow(1280, 600)
        .click(Selector('a').withText('TypeScript Support'))
})
```

I Want to scroll navigation bar and to click `TypeScript Support` link, but the whole window is scrolled, not navigation bar. Any workarounds here?

Answer (score 2):

The navigation menu uses a custom scrolling mechanism, therefore the auto scrolling mechanism should not work.
You should manually scroll to a required menu item using [the drag action](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/drag-element.html), for example: `.drag('.ps-scrollbar-y', 0, 600)`.